# Failed to locate the webdriver element using Selenium |

Tags: python, selenium

Using selenium automation webdriver i'm unable to locate the text box element on a travel website using python. Using locator present in the webdriver such as Id/name/css_selector/class_name or xpath/full xpath.
Below is the screenshot of the python code:
[Code_1][1]

While the first one is located the second one isn't. The corresponding HTML code is

[text_box2][2]

How can i fill(automate) both fileds corresponding flight destinations i.e leaving and going
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpoIr.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7mGs.jpg

Comment: uitk-faux-input appears to be a button, and you are trying to send it text? Better uitk-field-input? But why not locate by id location-field-leg1-destination?

Comment: from the html code it seems to be button but , issue is how to interact with the second filed "Gong to"

Comment: ok. Then I would try by ID as above

Comment: i tried, that locator seems nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach for locating things. I am using waits borrowed from CruisePandey in this thread. I used firefox, but that is adaptable. Some notes of what was hard:

I had to make sure to be on the Flights tab.
I had to click in the from and to fields, which were buttons after all, and then wait to be able to type into the revealed input fields.
Finally, I had to choose the first element from the dropdown list that resulted.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.expedia.co.in')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights")))
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Flights').click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "location-field-leg1-origin")))
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'uitk-faux-input').click()
fieldInput = driver.find_element_by_id('location-field-leg1-origin')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of(fieldInput))
fieldInput.send_keys("SFO")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "strong")))
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('strong').click()
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'uitk-faux-input')[1].click()
fieldInput = driver.find_element_by_id('location-field-leg1-destination')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of(fieldInput))
fieldInput.send_keys("BOS")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//strong[contains(text(), 'Boston')]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(text(), 'Boston')]").click()
```

Comment: i am late in posting the solution, this one got slightly better approach, thanks my only issue though is to automate from 1st placeholder to the second, but anyway thx again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the below xpath for going To input field :

```
//label[text()='Going to']//following-sibling::input[@name]
```

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Going to']//following-sibling::input[@name]"))).send_keys('something')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Yes, right , but neither of those locators mentioned earlier locates any elements in the ' Going to '

Comment: What do you mean ? I have written that customize locator by myself.. others can have different locators too.. try it out and let me know

Comment: File "expedia_auto.py", line 18, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Going to']//following-sibling::input[@name]"))).send_keys("NYC")
  File "C:\Users\MKBMX500\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: What new locator strategy i have to induce onto my code now ?

Comment: I am working on this right now, will let you know

Comment: i put, wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 just before the iteration of "Leaving from" & then i stored the same above element in 'a' variable , that is it

Comment: a = driver.find_element_by_class_name("uitk-faux-input")
a.send_keys("SFO")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='location-field-leg1-destination-menu']/div[1]/button"))).send_keys("NYC")

Comment: Now i' will check the next, dep. & ret. fields, will try to get into the check-in section of the website..to fully automate & let you know. if all goes right...

Comment: Do you still want me to work on this ticket ? if yes then let me know..

Comment: Ok, give 10 mins.

Comment: yeah, if you face anything let me know

Comment: Yes, it works successfully, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you want to automate from 1 place holder to another, i have use this set of code & it works for me

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='location-field-leg1-origin-menu']/div[2]/ul/li[1]/button"))).click()
b = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='location-field-leg1-destination-menu']/div[1]/button"))).send_keys("NYC")
b = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//*[@id='location-field-leg1-destination-menu']/div[2]/ul/li[1]/button"))).click()                                                         
c = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='d1-btn']"))).click()
```